# Unable to run any flutter commands 'The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory'

Tags: flutter

Whenever I run a flutter command including:

- flutter doctor
- flutter clean
- flutter channel [any channel]
- etc

I get the following error:

```
Gregorys-MacBook-Pro:~ gregory$ flutter doctor
Unhandled exception:
Exception: Flutter failed to create a directory at "/Users/gregory/.config/flutter". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      _throwFileSystemException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:749:3)
#2      _handlePosixException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:697:3)
#3      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:561:7)
#4      ErrorHandlingDirectory.createSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:408:12)
#5      new Config (package:flutter_tools/src/base/config.dart:33:17)
#6      runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:146:21)
#7      AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:41)
#8      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:311:23)
#9      AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#10     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#11     config (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:47:30)
#12     getBuildDirectory (package:flutter_tools/src/build_info.dart:673:48)
#13     defaultDepfilePath (package:flutter_tools/src/bundle.dart:29:55)
#14     new BuildBundleCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_bundle.dart:24:42)
#15     new BuildCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build.dart:33:19)
#16     main.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:102:5)
#17     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:50:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#20     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#21     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Just before I started getting this error I did the following:

- Deleted Library/developer/coresimulator/caches folder
- Changed flutter channel to `beta`

I was trying to get disk space for an xcode update.

Comment: Here is my git status in flutter folder: ```Gregorys-MacBook-Pro:flutter gregory$ git status
warning: unable to access '/Users/gregory/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
On branch beta
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/beta'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean```

Answer (score 30):

My problem was importing a project from Windows. I compared the imported folder with one that was created on MacOS and the difference was that appeared extended attribute. So my solution was to remove the extended attributes via command line:

```
$ sudo xattr -c -r  <project_folder>
```

Comment: this resolved my issue.

Comment: You are my live saver! 

Comment: I wasted more than 5 hours trying to figure it out without reinstalling my sdk.. Thanks a lot.. you saved me..

Answer (score 7):

I also faced same issue when i migrate flutter version to 2.0. Only the solution was grant permission to the user for that location.

you may simply run this command :

```
$ sudo chown -R <username> /Users/<username>/.config
```

should be replaced with your user name.

Answer (score 1):

go to flutter sdk folder then,inside bin folder open this path in terminal.now run a command "git stash"

now perform your command "flutter channel beta"

Comment: I seem to get the same problem ```Gregorys-MacBook-Pro:bin gregory$ git stash
warning: unable to access '/Users/gregory/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error listed, ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user. Are you sure flutter is not installed in a directory that requires superuser privileges?

Comment: Yes I am sure, it has not changed location since I installed it and I have never seen this error before. The actual location of my flutter folder is ```/Users/gregory/Dev/flutter``` so I'm not sure why it is saying ```.config/flutter```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why changing the channel to `beta` made the above happen, but what I did to solve it is give myself access to the `.config` folder, then changed back to `stable` channel.

I am now encountering different problems by flutter commands are working again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using vs code in windows, I just ran vs code as administrator and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

helps on MacOS

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, if you are on Windows follow these steps;

1. Go to **Windows Security**=>**Virus & threat protection**=>**Manage settings**=>**Controlled folder access**=>**Allow an app through Controlled folder access** .
2. **Click on Add an allowed app**
3. Here you can choose either **Recently blocked apps** or **Browse all apps**
4. Select from the list the apps you want to unblock.
   Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this issue for a long time [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73639155/11077173).
While installing flutter, getting this error. Not able to understand why this is happening every time. This time I try to remove the flutter completely.

After this step, when ever I try to run `flutter doctor`, that same red line appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this problem occur on MacOs and this is my solution:
`sudo xattr -c -r <folder path>`

Example: my folder path is "Users/Me/projects/DemoProject"

=> `sudo xattr -c -r Users/Me/projects/DemoProject`

Answer (score 0):

I enabled Full Disk Access for Visual Studio Code on Settings->Privacy & Security->Full Disk Access for macOS.