# Flutter Doctor not working on fresh install in my Mac Air M1 chip

Tags: android, flutter, macos, apple-m1, flutter-doctor

I've been trying to figure out the reason causing this error. I followed https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos and search other possible solutions in the internet but no luck. A help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Device: Macbook Air M1
OS: BigSur
Tried switching from stable - beta - stable. Setting - re-setting path. Changing permissions

````
melchorlapinig@Melchors-MacBook-Air development % flutter doctor -v

The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      _throwFileSystemException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:820:3)
#2      _handlePosixException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:761:3)
#3      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:614:7)
#4      ErrorHandlingProcessManager.runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:711:12)
#5      _DefaultProcessUtils.runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:373:51)
#6      AndroidStudio._init (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:458:39)
#7      new AndroidStudio (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:40:5)
#8      AndroidStudio.fromMacOSBundle (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:90:12)
#9      AndroidStudio._allMacOS.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:316:68)
#10     MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:413:31)
#11     ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:342:26)
#12     WhereTypeIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:869:20)
#13     new _GrowableList._ofOther (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:198:26)
#14     new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:152:26)
#15     new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:51:28)
#16     Iterable.toList (dart:core/iterable.dart:388:12)
#17     AndroidStudio._allMacOS (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:318:10)
#18     AndroidStudio.allInstalled (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:247:34)
#19     AndroidStudio.latestValid (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:232:41)
#20     AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:42)
#21     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:453:23)
#22     AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#23     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#24     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:119:24)
#25     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:119:24)
#26     androidStudio (package:flutter_tools/src/globals_null_migrated.dart:65:45)
#27     runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:104:32)
#28     AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:42)
#29     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:453:23)
#30     AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#31     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#32     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:119:24)
#33     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:119:24)
#34     androidLicenseValidator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_workflow.dart:28:65)
#35     DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:56:32)
#36     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1290:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#37     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1140:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#38     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#39     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#40     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#41     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#42     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#43     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#44     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#45     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
<asynchronous suspension>```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to run any flutter commands 'The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66146468/unable-to-run-any-flutter-commands-the-flutter-tool-cannot-access-the-file-or-d)

Comment: Thanks! Tried this also but no luck. I'll try to re-read again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solve. You can see solution here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96519

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You must update your environment $PATH variable.

1. Open the file $HOME/.zshrc $HOME is your home path
2. add the following line in the opened file:

   `export PATH="$PATH:/YOUR_FLUTTER_DIR/flutter/bin"`
3. save the changes and restart your terminal session.

The process is also documented [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path)

Comment: Yeah, i did it already a few times.

Comment: if the path was wrong the flutter command wouldn't even run

Comment: flutter command works. But if i add 'doctor' it would not.

Comment: please check with this command `which flutter dart` and set path again

Comment: Okay i will try. thanks

Comment: This  is the result: 

melchorlapinig@Melchors-MacBook-Air ~ % which flutter dart
/Users/melchorlapinig/development/flutter/bin/flutter
/Users/melchorlapinig/development/flutter/bin/dart