# The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory. Unable to grant read/write permissions for the current user

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, dart, terminal

This is the first time I am installing flutter on the mac. I have followed all the steps that are told in [flutter.dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWkwr.png). After setting up the path in `.zshrc`, I get this strange error.

> The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
> Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has
> read/write permissions for the current user.

This is the `.zshrc` file looks like.

[image]

After running `flutter doctor` getting this.

[image]

Also one thing, I have not created any projects yet. I just installed flutter. After installing flutter, whenever I am running `flutter doctor` I am getting this.

Adding `flutter doctor -v` below

```
The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has
read/write permissions for the current user.



#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      _throwFileSystemException
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:840:3)
#2      _handlePosixException
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:767:3)
#3      _handleMacOSException
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:781:3)
#4      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:619:7)
#5      ErrorHandlingProcessManager.runSync
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:717:12)
#6      _DefaultProcessUtils.runSync
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:376:51)
#7      AndroidStudio._init
(package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:469:39)
#8      new AndroidStudio
(package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:40:5)
#9      AndroidStudio.fromMacOSBundle
(package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:90:12)
#10     AndroidStudio._allMacOS.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:316:68)
#11     MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:415:31)
#12     ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:344:26)
#13     WhereTypeIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:871:20)
#14     new _GrowableList._ofOther (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:202:26)
#15     new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:152:26)
#16     new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:52:28)
#17     Iterable.toList (dart:core/iterable.dart:470:12)
#18     AndroidStudio._allMacOS
(package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:318:10)
#19     AndroidStudio.allInstalled
(package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:247:34)
#20     AndroidStudio.latestValid
(package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:232:41)
#21     AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:42)
#22     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent
(dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:535:23)
#23     AppContext._generateIfNecessary
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#24     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#25     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:119:24)
#26     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:119:24)
#27     androidStudio (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:62:45)
#28     runInContext.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:103:32)
#29     AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:42)
#30     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent
(dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:535:23)
#31     AppContext._generateIfNecessary
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#32     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#33     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:119:24)
#34     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:119:24)
#35     androidLicenseValidator
(package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_workflow.dart:30:65)
#36     DoctorCommand.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:53:32)
#37     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1426:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#38     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1257:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#39     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#40     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#41     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:283:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#42     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#43     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#44     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#45     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#46     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u find any solution to this?

Comment: Not yet @JolsonDaCosta.

Comment: i created new user and was able to run flutter successfully there .  not sure what was wrong in existing one

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this issue when moving my project from windows to a Mac folder. It seems to be an issue with some extended attributes. Using the below command worked for me.

```
sudo xattr -c -r  <project_folder_path>
```

Comment: Tried this. Not working. In my MacBook Air, after upgrading the SSD from 128 GB to 1TB, I am facing this strange issue. Till now it is not resolved.

Comment: Have you tried @Zeyad Alhababi s answer by applying it to the root folder > press the lock icon > dropdown menu > apply to enclosed items...

Comment: Yes, I did that also. Not working.

Comment: Working fine for me. MacOS BigSur and flutter 3.3.10 (stable version)

Comment: is there a windows ersion of this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this but try it. go to the folder where you installed Flutter, click the folder with two fingers or `Cmd I` to show options. On the {Get info} screen look down at the Sharing & Permission, make sure your current user has read and write.

[image]
I just hope this will fix your problem

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have tried this also but not working.

Answer (score 1):

My 3 hours research i found result this is my problem ->
Flutter failed to delete a directory at "build". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.

---

### Solution

Anti-virus or Security Software:

If you have anti-virus or security software running on your computer, it might be blocking the deletion of files in the 'build' directory. Try temporarily disabling it and then running flutter clean again.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 11 on VScode it shows the same problem. Another way to fix, is to run VScode with Admin Privilleges

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Just create a new folder on your new device then move your project there.

Comment: Without creating any project we can write `flutter doctor` right? Read the problem properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).