# Flutter error while try to run in macbook m1

Tags: flutter, permissions, apple-m1, flutter-run

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Exception: The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.

Exited

but when with other flutter projects it can be built but this project can't

[image]

Comment: Maybe related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73639155/the-flutter-tool-cannot-access-the-file-or-directory-unable-to-grant-read-write

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. There is some extended attribute issue.
Use this command

```
sudo xattr -c -r  <project_folder_path>
```

Read the man page of [xattr](https://ss64.com/osx/xattr.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem on mac m1 macos Ventura.
Solution:
Go to the directory: /Users/{username}/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/Accounts/E525FE04-C02F-4E84-9EB7-F2F8CF38E443(ID may be different)/Media, find the directory with Android Studio files, delete everything, restart Android Studio and configure. After that the flutter doctor/run/build command does not give an error message:

The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.