# Unable to generate release build for android for Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-release

I am trying to create release build for Android. But I am facing following error:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            11ms
Flutter failed to run "/Users/Developer/taxi_token/android/gradlew -q -Ptarget-platform=android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
-Ptarget=lib/main.dart -Pbase-application-name=android.app.Application -Pdart-obfuscation=false -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=true
assembleRelease".
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
```

Comment: Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/q/73639155/12965265

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investing some hours I found the solution:

```
$ sudo xattr -c -r <project_folder>
```

For reference go through the [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70216)